# responsive text highlighting for each row of a text located inside a span

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

as you can see in the link [here](http://91.202.168.37/~rootsnew/home-page-2/).
I highlighted the dark gray text (under 'roots profile' title) with a light gray background. The php code looks like that:

```
<div class="hp_subtitle" id="rb_sub1">
    <span class="spank">
        <?php the_field( "rp_subtitle" ); ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

The text is coming from an ACF and can be of any length. what I want is that for each line there will be a 10px for padding-left and padding-right, regardless of the number of lines. That because I want my website to be responsive and the size of the screen obviously affects the number of lines this text will have.
right now the padding of course works only at the first left and last right, since it is attended as a one line.
Is there a way to select the line with Jquery or JS? so it can add the attributes dynamically after the line breaks because of the screen size?
[That's only two rows, but that's how i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Yp9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
.spank {
    background: #d7d7d7;
    line-height: 1.8;
    position: relative;
    top: -7px;
    left: -10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you are supposed to add some explanation along with the code too...